# Print record in template

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am trying to print records in template here is problem with one field **`itemDesc`**: this field is optional, some time user not insert any data in that field at that when I am trying to print records at that time it by default print `0`, but I don't want to print anything at that time. I don't know why it's print `0` when user not fill any data in that field.

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Item Name</td>
</tr>

{section name="sec" loop=$billDetailArray}
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="billdetaildelete.php?billdetailId={$billDetailArray[sec].billdetailId}" onclick="return myFunction();" class="link" ><img src="./images/delete.png"></a>
    </td>
    <td>{$billDetailArray[sec].itemName}{$billDetailArray[sec].itemDesc}</td>
{/section}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use isset():

```
{if isset($billDetailArray[sec].itemDesc) && $billDetailArray[sec].itemDesc !== 0}
    {$billDetailArray[sec].itemName}{$billDetailArray[sec].itemDesc}
{/if}
```

i dont know you have on default an integer in **itemDesc**. If not change the && statement to that what you need !== '0', != 0,...